# Python Same Period Last Year in Pandas with GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, offset, forecasting

I have following DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 72

dates = list(pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01',periods=n,freq='MS'))
products = ['a','b','c']
countries = ['a','b','c']

df = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame({'product':products}), pd.DataFrame({'country':countries}),how='cross')
df = pd.merge(df, pd.DataFrame({'ds':dates}),how='cross')

df['y'] = np.random.default_rng(12345).integers(low=200,high=1000,size=len(df))
```

How do I copy 'y' from same month last year to current month? 
What I need is:

| ds | product | country | y | last_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 | a | a | 759 | NaN |
| 2016-01-01 | b | a | 330 | NaN |
| 2016-01-01 | c | a | 794 | NaN |
| 2016-02-01 | a | b | 633 | NaN |
| ... | .. | .. | .. | ... |
| 2017-01-01 | a | a | 654 | 759 |
| 2017-01-01 | b | a | 295 | 330 |
| 2017-01-01 | c | a | 969 | 794 |
| ... | .. | .. | .. | ... |
| 2017-02-01 | a | b | 464 | 636 |
| ... | .. | .. | .. | ... |
| 2021-12-01 | b | c | 498 | 722 |
| ... | .. | .. | .. | ... |

I have tried following with no success:

```py
df.set_index('ds',inplace=True)
df['last_year'] = df.groupby(['product', 'country']).y.shift(freq='12MS').reset_index()['y']
```

Shows NaN in all rows

And

```py
df = df.groupby(['product', 'country'])['y'].rolling(12).apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

gives

```py
KeyError: -1
```

Hope you can assist!.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your expected result. You can try this :

```
df['last_year'] = df['y'].shift(12)
```